# Django: returning count values

Tags: django

With the following code I want to return the count this works...

```
def contact_count(self):
    return len(self.contacts)
```

However, if the len is 0 is returns blank and I want it to be 0.

So I have tried

```
def contact_count(self):
    if len(self.contacts) == 0:
       return 0
    else:
      return len(self.contacts)
```

Is there a better way I should be handling this?

**UPDATE:**

So to update my question as asked this is how contacts is defined...

models.py

```
class Groups(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    def contact_count(self):
        return len(self.contacts)

class Contacts(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    #FK
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Groups, related_name='contacts')
```

As you can see if comes from the related_name

Comment: how is `contacts` defined?

Comment: `return 0 if not self.contact else len(self.contacts)` although it's only a matter of style really as what you have works

Comment: what do you mean len(self.contacts) returns blank? Maybe you get error page because you're trying to len(None) which is exception?

Comment: see update above to show where contacts comes from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `self.contacts.count()`.

See [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/queries/#many-to-many-relationships) on many to many relations for more details.